# When creating an HTML table with D3, use certain data for a row class rather than cell

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table

I'v created a table with D3 from a 2 level array:

```
var columns = ["Id", "Book  Title", "Author"];
var books = [
    ["1", "The Caves of Steel", "Isaac Asimov"],
    ["2", "The Robots of Dawn", "Isaac Asimov"],
    ["3", "Brave New World", "Aldous Huxley"],
    ["4", "1984", "George Orwell"],
];

var table = d3.select("body").append("table").attr("id", "bookTable");
var thead = table.append("thead");
var tbody = table.append("tbody");

thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
        .text(function ( d ) { return d; })

var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(books)
    .enter()
    .append("tr").attr("data-id", function( d ){  return d[0]; });

var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function ( d ) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function( d ) { return d; });
```

In this example, the array is defined statically, but in my file it's being constructed from a database query. I need to include the id for the row because the user is able to delete any row but clicking a button that is added to each row later with jquery, and the id is how I am identifying what row from the database to delete, but I don't want it displaying as a column in the table, I want to apply it as a "data-id" attribute on the table row.

Right now, a column for the id is created in the table in the table as well as creating the tr attribute, which is why id is included in the array of columns above, but this will need to be removed.

How can I tell d3 to skip the id when appending td's and instead use this data for the data-id attribute on the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the easiest way to do this is to make your `data` an array of Objects, instead of just an Array, e.g.

```
{id: 1, book: ["The Caves of Steel", "Isaac Asimov"], ...}
```

Then you can set the `data-id` of each row using the `id` attribute, and add `td`s for the `book`. Here's the code I used to get your example working:

```
// Add the header
thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns.slice(1, columns.length)) // skip the first column (IDs)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
        .text(function ( d ) { return d; })

// Reformat the nested Arrays into an Array of Objects,
// then set the 'data-id' of each row
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(books.map(function(d){ return {id: d[0], book: d.slice(1, d.length)}; }))
    .enter()
    .append("tr").attr("data-id", function( d ){  return d.id; });

// Append the author and title for each book
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function ( d ) { return d.book; })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function( d ) { return d; });
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when using this code: 'Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slice''. This is catching the second time slice is used, under rows.

Comment: @Alex: that's strange, I don't get an error using the same code. Can you put `console.log(d);` before the `return ...` statement on that line and tell me what it says? When I do this, I get [this output](http://f.cl.ly/items/3U3I3Z283T0f1h1F0t3m/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-07%20at%203.49.07%20PM.png).

Comment: Oh, I see what happened. I changed my data be an array of objects, like [this](http://cl.ly/image/2m0g273j2T13) because I thought that's what you meant in the first part of your answer. When I did that, I got [this from the log](http://cl.ly/image/01292B1k2L2R).
When I changed the books var back to an array of arrays, it worked and I got [this](http://cl.ly/image/0h2N1D3e450S).

Comment: @Alex: okay I understand now, sorry for the confusion. If you change your data structure so it's an Array of Objects, then you should be able to just use `.data(books)`. This is probably easier to read, but I'm not sure if your database can provide your data in that format. Otherwise does it work as expected?

Comment: It does! I just didn't catch that you had formatted the data into an array of objects within the d3 code and assumed I needed to do this before hand. That's what I get for copying and pasting... Thanks for the help!